# python pyz7r getting "Unsupported feature" when unzipping after zipping

Tags: python, windows, zip, archive, 7zip

I am trying to use `pyz7r` Python module to zip some folders I have, what I want is to make sure the folders is zipped into the archive as the following:

```
Here are my folders.

SomeFolder.
  - File1.txt
  - File2.txt
AnotherOne
  - Wow.txt
  - IAmAFile.txt

I want the output after creating the 7z file and unzip it to be as the following:

UnzippedFolder
  SomeFolder.
    - File1.txt
    - File2.txt
  AnotherOne
    - Wow.txt
    - IAmAFile.txt
```

I heard about using this:

```py
folders = ["./SomeFolder", "./AnotherOne"]

with py7zr.SevenZipFile("Zipped.7z", 'w') as archive:
    for folder in folders:
        print(f"Zipping {folder}....")
        archive.writeall(FOLDER)
        print("DONE!")
```

Everything till here is fine, until when I try to unzip the folder using 7zip program it returns the following error:

*Cannot open the file as [7z] archive*
*Unsupported feature*

I am not sure where is the problem. Also I didn't ever try the `writeall` (or didn't ever work for me) function but what I know it does the the same files and folders order I want.

I am on Windows 11 if that helps.